# How to connect Visual Studio to a SQL Server data base remote by IP?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, connection

I have two virtual machines one with *Windows Server 2008* and *SQL Server 2012*, and  other with *Windows 7* and *Visual Studio*.
I need to connect simple webform project to a database. When I use the machine's name, I mean the computer name of the machine with Windows Server 2008 in the `web.config`, It run but when I use the IP, it fails!?

Comment: try to connect `IP,PORT` in connection string

Comment: I have Data Source=192.168.20.3,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Comment: You need to enable TCP/IP protocol in Sql Server configuration on the server and make sure port 1433 is opened in the firewall.

Comment: I've already started in sql server configuration manager the TCP/IP

Comment: am I forgeting something?

Comment: 1) in the sql native client config or the server connection?  2) what about the port in firewall?

Comment: What edition of SQL (Standard, Wed, or the dreaded Express?)

Comment: server connection and standard

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue? @user3152420